# Dealing with very low animation frame-rates

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, animation, directx

**Here's the scenario:**

I've got a series of many views primarily containing listboxes. Listboxes, some with large amounts of data in them, some with very little.
Currently, I've got an attached behaviour that essentially just detects when new content has been loaded into the container for these views (a `ContentPresenter`) and triggers a simple XAML storyboard that offsets the container by 200px to the left, or to the right, and also lowers the opacity to 0% (at 0ms) then over 100ms it restores the opacity to 100% and reduces the offset back to 0px, creating a 'sliding into view' sort of effect.

**Now, the issue:**

The framerate of this animation varies horribly anywhere from a smooth transition to jittery, to outright just lagging at 1 frame until completion.
This is almost certainly due to the fact it's having to load the new view, render everything in it, then even further; lists with loads of data in them need even more render time, THEN whilst all that's happening it's trying to animate its location changing which seems to drastically affect the performance of the animation.

it shocks me that something as simple as moving some pixels across the screen is so graphically intensive for WPF to handle

*Here's a crude representation of the animation itself:*
[image]

**My question:**

Is there any sort of fundamental best-practice for dealing with intensive animations in WPF so as to improve their performance, or any kinds of small changes to things that when added up boost performance?
Or is WPF just terrible at animating and we just have to deal with it.

Comment: Have you got `Virtualization`enabled in your `ListView`s? If not look into a `VirtualizingStackPanel`.

Comment: Yes, they all have that, so my guess is that the datatemplates of some list box items are complex enough sometimes that even a few showing is enough to slow things down

Comment: Make sure that the virtualization is working on your `ListView`s, I have had a problem with those in the past. Do you use normal Binding for `ItemsSource` or do you use `CollectionViewSource`? Could you also post a `XAML` of your ListView's with included Virtualization?

Answer (score 1):

I've come up with a solution which, in my case, has always solved the jitter problem. It is certainly worth trying. The strategy is to take any element that **will not change throughout the animation**, insert it in a local reference framework such as a grid or canvas, make that grid or canvas store cached versions of its content, and then apply your animation to the grid or canvas, rather than the inside elements. It is as simple as this:

```
<Canvas ...Your canvas properties...>
    <Canvas.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache />
    </Canvas.CacheMode>
    ...Your UI elements...
</Canvas>
```

or, for a grid:

```
<Grid ...Your grid properties...>
    <Grid.CacheMode>
        <BitmapCache />
    </Grid.CacheMode>
    ...Your UI elements...
</Grid>
```

You'll want to simply ensure that you do not update anything inside the canvas (or grid), as this will undo the cached version and you'll find yourself with a similar issue where WPF will regenerate its rendering on every frame.

By having cached versions of the content, what WPF will be moving across the screen is not a dynamically updated element, it is simply a bitmap of the last render of that element, and WPF will update that bitmap only if changes are applied to the element.

If that does not solve your issues, it means that performance is hindered by something occurring outside the generation of the local element. This means you'll want to look at your overall application, or reduce the entire frame rate of your application. However, in virtually all cases of jittering and jerky movements I found for my WPF animations, the BitmapCache solution seems to work all the time. Just be careful in not applying animations to objects inside the element being cached.

Comment: Thank you for the advice i tested it and it works , i improved my app perforamnce by a mile. I approve it

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem is, that you try to do everything at the same time or same thread. Just try to do it async in splitted tasks. There are plenty of different approaches to that. Another approach would be to just handle the work with a semaphore, this should push your performance a bit up.

Comment: You might be right - asynchronicity is something we need to look into much more.